# Express.js api taking forever to response (not responding at all)

Tags: javascript, express

I'm new to Express.js (and learning MERN stack), my api/auth endpoint is taking forever to response (it shows "Processing..." in thunder client but request never gets to an end) I know this can happen in Express.js but don't know why this happens, if anyone knows please help!

index.js

```
const connectToMongo = require("./db.js")
const express = require('express')
connectToMongo()
const app = express()
const port = 3000

// middlewares
app.use(express.json())



// Available routes
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/auth") )
app.use("/api/notes", require("./routes/notes") )

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port http://127.0.0.1:${port}`)
})
```

db.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongoURI = "mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017"

const connectToMongo = async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(mongoURI)
    console.log("connected to MongoDB successfully")
}

module.exports = connectToMongo;
```

auth.js

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const User = require("../models/User")
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

router.post("/", [
  body('username').isLength({ min: 3 }),
  body("email").isEmail,
  body('password').isLength({ min: 6 }),

], (req, res) => {
  res.send("aa")
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }
  User.create({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
  }).then(user => res.json(user));
})

module.exports = router;
```

User model in mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;


const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

Comment: You cannot execute both `res.send` and `res.json` for one request.

Comment: okay but it does not help (I'm not trying to be rude)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was not calling `body("email").isEmail()` so I needed to change this `body("email").isEmail` to `body("email").isEmail()`

***"I know this can happen in Express.js but don't know why this happens"***
To my experience this happens when an uncaught error occurs (yes on some kind or errors JS will not throw an error) and the api program stops and a error is not thrown or it could stop for any reason like infinite loop, logical error etc.

BTW I also needed to put `email: req.body.email` in `User.create()`